# Javascript Trigonometry Problems

Tags: javascript, html, trigonometry

I'm trying to make an application where a group of humans/bacteria chase each other. However, if I try to make them go directly towards their target, they all move to the left instead. (I say "target" because one side targets a member of the other.) I tried using trigonometry, where you have the initial x,y coordinates, but I have to find the next x,y coordinates with the slope and distance to travel known. Here's my relevant code:

```
/*Functions for calculating next x, y*/
function calculate_nextX(startx, length, slope)
{
    var x = 0;
    var degree = Math.atan(slope);
    x = (startx + (length * Math.sin(degree * 0.0174)));
    return x;
}
function calculate_nextY(starty, length, slope)
{
    var y = 0;
    var degree = Math.atan(slope);
    y = (starty + (length * Math.cos(degree * 0.0174)));
    return y;
}

/*Where the functions get used*/

function updateeverything()
{
    for(var i=0;i<=49;i++)
    {
        if(bacteriaGroup[i].dead == false)
        {
            if(humanGroup[bacteriaGroup[i].target].dead == true)
            {
                bacteriaGroup[i].target = settarget(true,i);
            }
            var left = parseInt(document.getElementById("bacteria"+i).style.left);
            var left1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("human"+bacteriaGroup[i].target).style.left);
            var top = parseInt(document.getElementById("bacteria"+i).style.top);
            var top1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("human"+bacteriaGroup[i].target).style.top);

            var finalleft = calculate_nextX(left,1,(top1-top)/(left1-left));
            var finaltop = calculate_nextY(top,1,(top1-top)/(left1-left));
            document.getElementById("bacteria"+i).style.left = finalleft;
            document.getElementById("bacteria"+i).style.top = finaltop;
        }
        if(humanGroup[i].dead == false)
        {
            if(bacteriaGroup[humanGroup[i].target].dead == true)
            {
                humanGroup[i].target = settarget(false,i);
            }
            var left = parseInt(document.getElementById("human"+i).style.left);
            var left1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("bacteria"+humanGroup[i].target).style.left);
            var top = parseInt(document.getElementById("human"+i).style.top);
            var top1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("bacteria"+humanGroup[i].target).style.top);
            var finalleft = calculate_nextX(left,1,(top1-top)/(left1-left));
            var finaltop = calculate_nextY(top,1,(top1-top)/(left1-left));
            document.getElementById("human"+i).style.left = finalleft;
            document.getElementById("human"+i).style.top = finaltop;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
(top1-top)/(left1-left)
```

has the same value whether the target is up and to the left or down and to the right.  This could be the root of your problems.

I propose:

```
var distance_to_target = sqrt((top1-top)*(top1-top) + (left1-left)*(left1-left));
var fraction_of_distance = length / distance_to_target;
var dx = (left1 - left) * fraction_of_distance;
var dy = (top1 - top) * fraction_of_distance;
```

Note also that css locations get rounded to the nearest integer, so if you're moving by small amounts, you'll need to do work on logical locations and then round them at the end.

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe I totally goofed up on c = a*a + b*b. Also, even when I fixed the input, it still didn't work, but when I tried your suggestion, it worked perfectly! However, I just want to point out that to line 3 and 4 of your suggestion that I had to add "left + (the rest)" and "top + (the rest)". Otherwise, thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

Your `slope` does not distinguish between moving to top and bottom / between left and right - it's only the ratio of `x/y`. To get the `degree`, you need both `x` and `y` value and need to use the [`atan2` function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) (in JS, [`Math.atan2`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2)).

However, I don't see a reason to use degrees for the direction at all. You can easily (and much faster) compute the next coordinates by using the simple [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).